# Partition alignment 8 TB seagate Ironwolf

Tags: debian

I have a Seagate disk that I am trying to get partition aligned. I've tried this command in parted:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt

sudo parted -a opt /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
```

**Get this fdisk error:**

```
Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1  65535 15628000379 15627934845  7.3T Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

**How do I get this disk partion aligment in parted ?**

(I've also tried this guide: https://rainbow.chard.org/2013/01/30/how-to-align-partitions-for-best-performance-using-parted/

unsuccessfully)

**A little info about harddrive:**

```
root@odroidxu4:~# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/optimal_io_size 33553920
root@odroidxu4:~# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/minimum_io_size 4096
root@odroidxu4:~# cat /sys/block/sda/alignment_offset 0
root@odroidxu4:~# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/physical_block_size 4096
root@odroidxu4:~# hdparm -I /dev/sda

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST8000VN0022-2EL112
    Serial Number:      ZA1CH2SF
    Firmware Revision:  SC61
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SAT                                                                                        A Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0

Configuration:
    Logical         max     current
    cylinders       16383   16383
    heads           16      16
    sectors/track   63      63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors: 15628053168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     7630885 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     8001563 MBytes (8001 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 3.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
```

Comment: Please format your code/data blocks. Select each block in turn and use the `{}` button on the editing menu to indent it four spaces. Also ensure there's a blank line above and below each block. (I'd do it for you if i weren't on a mobile device that doesn't have `{}`.)

Comment: get rid of -a opt and use mib instead of %

Comment: I am not a linux nerd can you write full command  frostschutz  ?

Comment: As I understand "-a opt" to tell parted to must align (optimal) but why it doesn't work I don't understand? When I check if it is aligned in parted it is ok but not in fdisk :/

Comment: `parted /dev/sda mkpart PARTITION_NAME ext4 1MiB 100%`

Comment: So if i use this "parted /dev/sda mkpart PARTITION_NAME ext4 1MiB 100%" it will be aligent ?

Comment: I have try to use this "parted /dev/sda mkpart PARTITION_NAME ext4 1MiB 100%" but get :

Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
Ignore/Cancel?

Why alex ?

Comment: @ReneMortensen MiB alignment is good for everything (exception: [drives with off-by-one jumper](https://support.wdc.com/images/kb/adv_format_jumper.jpg)) so just ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use parted, as it is obviously not up to the job. To partition a GPT disk, use `gdisk`. Alternatively, if your version of `fdisk` understands GPT partitions, you can use that as well. Just delete the partition and create a new partition. Format the partition with `mkfs.ext4`. Note that doing so will destroy any data you already have written to the disk.

Comment: `parted` is perfectly able to do the job. Just tell it where to put the partition. It accepts exact positioning at the level of sectors.

Comment: @AlexP Well, why don't you show how to use `parted` to create a partition that is aligned so that the starting sector is a multiple of eight (required by the physical sector size of the disk)? Gdisk does this automatically.

Comment: `parted` <disk> `mkpart` <partition_name> <filesystem_type> <start> <end>, where <start> and <end> can be given in sectors (e.g., `2048s`), binary megabytes (e.g., `1MiB`) etc.

Comment: Now I have tried Gdisk and it seems to work out of the box but what should I choose in :

Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 

Is just a linux etx4 share on debian

Comment: The default value 8300 stands for "Linux filesystem", which is OK in this case.